# Select2(4.00) return undefined in onSelect event when useing ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using Select2 (ver 4.00) and loading remote data with ajax method.

I need to retrieve title of selected option, but in select2:select event data is undifined

my code:

```
 $(".js-data-action-terms").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: ajaxurl + "?action=terms",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data.items
            };
        },
        cache: false
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});

$('.js-data-action-terms').on("select2:select", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Result log:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Select2 4.0.0, the selected object was moved from the `evt.data` property to `evt.params.data`. Now all extra data for events in Select2 is put in `evt.params` for consistency.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I am looking for!